# Two event Listeners overlapping Javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```
document.querySelector(".profile_icon").addEventListener("click",function(e){ 
    document.querySelector(".profile").classList.add("show");
    
});
document.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e){
    var container = document.getElementById('profile');
    if(!container.contains(e.target)){
        document.querySelector(".profile").classList.remove("show");
    }
 });
```

When i click on profile icon the drop drop appears but if i click on icon again, it doesnt disappear as window event listener overlaps with the icon event listener. I want the menu to close both when user clicks outise the profile box as well as on the icon button.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us a bit more of your (HTML) code. It's not enough to go into

Answer (score 1):

You are always adding the class and never removing it in the icon event handler

Try using `toggle()` instead of `add()`

```
document.querySelector(".profile_icon").addEventListener("click",function(e){ 
    document.querySelector(".profile").classList.toggle("show");        
});
```

Comment: Provide a runnable [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. you can create one that runs right here in the page by clicking on `<>` in question editor and adding just enough html, js and css to make it run

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change mouseup to mousedown event. If you use the mouse up, click on the profile icon will add the show class and mouseup will be activated just when you raise your hand. But in this scenario, if you use the mousedown event, your next move will be processed good than that.

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){ // Only change this line.
   var container = document.getElementById('profile');
   if(!container.contains(e.target)){
       document.querySelector(".profile").classList.remove("show");
   }
});
```